# ¿Se puede mostrar el log de una app ionic dentro de la misma?

Tags: javascript, ionic, xcode, cordova

Lo que necesito es que el log que normalmente se muestra en el debugger de Chrome, Safari o Xcode, se muestre en una pantalla oculta dentro de la propia aplicación.

¿Es esto posible?

Comment: Si son console log de javascript, puedes echarle un vistazo a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403107/capturing-javascript-console-log)

Comment: Gracias Javier, tiene muy buena pinta. Si que es log de javascript así que a ver si puedo adaptarlo para que saque por una pantalla mi app ionic el log...

Comment: Perfecto, prueba y nos comentas. Básicamente lo que tienes que hacer es sobre escribir la función console.log, suerte!